# Perl in an .Rnw file: the 'tilde' character

Tags: r, knitr

I'd like to write a report that contains both R code and perl, so to test things out, I added the following snippet (borrowed from [028-engine-perl.Rmd](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/028-engine-perl.Rmd)) to the end of the file [002-minimal.Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/002-minimal.Rnw) (I called the resulting file Minimal.Rnw):

```
<<CheckPerl>>=
Sys.which('perl')
@

<<TestPerl, engine='perl'>>=
$test = "jello world";
$test =~ s/j/h/;
print $test
@
```

When I knit() the file (in emacs, using M-n s), Minimal.tex is produced, and the result of the substitution is correct, e.g.,

```
...
\begin{verbatim}
## hello world
\end{verbatim}
...
```

However, when I try to produce the .pdf file, I get the following error message:

```
...
./Minimal.tex:108: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.108 ...\hlkwb{\$test\ }\hlstd{}\hlopt{=$\sim$\ }
                                                  \hlstd{}\hlkwc{s/j/h/}\hls...

? 
./Minimal.tex:108: Emergency stop.
...
```

The statement in l.108 (and others) are within the `alltt` environment, but according to the documentation for `alltt`, the `$` symbol just produces a dollar sign, and is not used to denote mathmode. So, if I manually replace `$\sim$` by `\(\sim\)`, I get a .tex file that compiles correctly and gives me the expected result.

So, after all that, my question is: how can I get knitr to use `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` in the `alltt` environment?

(R-3.0.1, emacs 23.3.1, ess 13.05, Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been fixed in [the knitr development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) (`>= v1.4.8`). Andre Simon's Highlight does not assume the `alltt` environment, so `knitr` should not put the highlighted code in the `alltt` environment.

Comment: I installed the latest version from rforge, and it works fine now. Thanks.